# Android Cursor not looping through rows

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have this table in SQLite
[image]
and then I have this code with which I want to get all the row values

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbModel.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT cig_for_this_day FROM program WHERE stage = 2", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int rows = c.getCount();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            int j = c.getInt(0);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
```

it gets the count all right, but every time it loops it returns 12, why is that happening, I want it to move all the way to the end of the column

Comment: You've never used variable (j)...

Comment: I am debuging it and checking directly the value of c.getInt(0), and every time it loops it is 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the loop like this:

```
...
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int rows = c.getCount();
    do {
        int j = c.getInt(0);
        // Do something with j
    } while(c.moveToNext());
}
...
```

Comment: still staying on the same row

Comment: @Sartheris : Are you sure you've populated the table correctly and haven't written 12 to every row in the table?

Comment: @Sartheris : Try adding something like `int pos = c.getPosition();` into the loop. It will tell you what row you are on each time.

Comment: while looping c.getPosition() returns only 1

Comment: Check your query logic. Are all the rows has value 12 where stage = 2?

Comment: no, look at the picture, those are the rows where stage = 2

Comment: @Sartheris : `getPosition()` only returning 1 makes no sense - a row set returned to a `Cursor` is zero-based (for the rows themselves) although the initial query will set the position to -1 (before the first row). By calling `moveToFirst()`, the position will be 0 and not 1. Any successful call to `moveToNext()` will increment the position returned until the position goes past the last row at which point it will be equal to `getCount()`.

Comment: well I dont know either, but thats the code I am using right now, debuging it, and getting the results I am telling you